# php do while loop, display plus sign between results

Tags: php, do-while

I would want to display a plus sign between my do while loop result as illustrated below:

If i get two results i would want it to display as e.g. `46+56`  and if three results `45+76+89`.

Where do i place the **plus sign** + so that it does not display at the ends?

```
  <?php do { ?>
  + <?php echo $row_studentcat['marks']; ?> 
  <?php } while ($row_studentcat = mysql_fetch_assoc($studentcat)); ?>
```

The code above would display result as **+45+56**  but i would want it to display as **45+56**

Any help..

Comment: try: `ltrim($string,'+');`

Comment: Get all results into an array and just `implode('+', $results)` them.

Comment: @Uchiha: left side, got it friend.

Answer (score 1):

For removing `+` sign from starting (left side), you can use [`ltrim()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ltrim.php) function:

**Example:**

```
$Yourstring = '+45+10';
echo ltrim($Yourstring,'+'); //45+10
```

Second param of Function [`ltrim()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ltrim.php) will remove the starting `+` from your string.

**[From PHP Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ltrim.php):**

> ltrim — Strip whitespace (or other characters) from the beginning of a
>   string

Comment: I have tried but not working     <?php 
 $plus = '+';
 $string1 = $row_studentcat['marks']; 
 
 $string = "$plus$string1";
   
 echo ltrim($string,'+');
   
 ?>

Comment: @krushiovida: work for me, what is the value of `$row_studentcat['marks']`?

Comment: @krushiovida: its better to use array for this . did u try with array?

Comment: I have combined your answer with Manjeet answer for it to work     `<?php 
 
  $marksArray[] = $row_studentcat['marks'];
 $join = join('+',$marksArray);
  
   echo ltrim($join,'+');
 ?>`

Comment: @krushiovida: u r the king.

Answer (score 1):

You should use the [ltrim()](http://php.net/manual/de/function.ltrim.php) function instead:

```
echo ltrim($s,'+');
```

Otherwise, rtrim() will do the same right hand side

Answer (score 1):

I would implode the data so I can store the data from the other columns in other variables.

```
$marks = array();
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($studentcat)) {
    $marks[] = $row['marks'];
}

echo implode('+', $marks);
```

Answer (score 1):

This is very simple my friend, use php `JOIN()`...

```
<?php 
$marksArray= array()l
while ($row_studentcat = mysql_fetch_assoc($studentcat))
{
    $marksArray[] = $row_studentcat['marks'];
}
echo join('+',$marksArray);
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

The faster way is concatenating the elements into a string and delete the first + using this method:

```
substr($string, 1);
```

Comparing with *implode* is 3 times faster and comparing with *ltrim* is a little bit faster because we **only change the index array** in this case, which is faster than remove an element

Furthermore, I would like to comment you **two important issues** of this code:

1. In case *mysql_fetch_assoc* returns you an empty result you will have an error, because you will try to access to an **unexisting index array**, better use *while(){}*
2. The method *mysql_fetch_assoc* is **deprecated and is removed in PHP7**, your code will have problems in the future: http://php.net/manual/es/function.mysql-fetch-assoc.php